# Passing cursor record to a function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have a stored procedure.  I want to call a function from it.  Want to pass the retrieved cursor record to the function.  how can i pass the retrieved cursor record as function argument and how can i access it inside the function?  How do i declare the function?

> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  service__update as
>
> ```
> cursor c_getData is
>     select    *
>     from  service_1
>     where status=5    ;
>
>
> begin
>     dbms_output.enable(null);    
>
>     for rec in c_getData loop
>
>     function(rec)
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you really want a function (which implies that you want to return a value) rather than a procedure (which does not return a value) and assuming that your cursor really is selecting every column from a single table, you can declare a function that takes an anchored `%ROWTYPE`

```
SQL> create function get_empno( p_rec in emp%rowtype )
  2    return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return p_rec.empno;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.
```

and then call that function from your procedure

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_empno emp.empno%type;
  3  begin
  4    for i in (select * from emp)
  5    loop
  6      l_empno := get_empno( i );
  7      dbms_output.put_line( l_empno );
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
7369
7499
7521
7566
7654
7698
7782
7788
7839
7844
7876
7900
7902
7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  we use oracle 10g.  In Oracle is there a way to modify the cursor records.  In my question posted earlier, I am using the rec variable to store the record retrieved from the cursor.  Will i be able to modify a particular column of  the record  rec.service_active=sysdate and later on can i commit it to the tables?

Comment: @Arav - No.  A REF CURSOR is a read-only structure in Oracle.  You could, of course, read the data from the record and use that data in a subsequent `UPDATE` statement against the underlying table.